# show grand children for table person with SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `person(ID,fname,Age,Gender,parentID)`,
can anyone tell how to show persons who *do not have* **grand childrens** in **SQL**?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, but might be a bit slow if you have a lot of people with a lot of children:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM person p 
LEFT JOIN person c ON c.parentID = p.ID
LEFT JOIN person gc on gc.parentID = c.ID
WHERE gc.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM person 
WHERE 
ID NOT IN (
          SELECT id 
          FROM (
                SELECT p.*,c.id as childID,g.id AS grandChildId
                FROM person p 
                LEFT JOIN person c 
                ON c.parentID = p.ID 
                LEFT JOIN person g 
                ON g.parentID = c.ID
               ) AS person_relation 
          WHERE grandChildId 
          is NOT NULL
```

Creating temporary tables can be helpful but for a single query this will work .